# Is an instance of a class automatically created when you first call a static method

Tags: java, instance, static-methods

I would like to know if you have a class with only static methods in it, does an actual instance of the class get created somewhere when you call 1st static method?

This is somewhat confusing to understand in terms of memory management as you never actually call the constructor or create an instance of the method explicitly.

If an instance does get created, I would like to better understand where this instance lives and for how long.

Comment: You're confusing class loading (which creates `Class` objects and various VM-specific metadata) with object instantiation.  (Note that abstract classes can have static methods -- no hidden automagic instantiation would be possible.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Calling a `static` method does not require (or create) an instance of a `class`. See also [JLS-8.4.3.2 `static` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2) which says (in part)

> A method that is declared `static` is called a class method.

...

> A class method is always invoked without reference to a particular object.

Comment: Thank you this helps. A parallel question, lets say you create an anonymous class inside a static method, what happens to the parent reference that is assigned to the anonymous class (as in java anonymous and inner classes by default get a strong reference back to enclosing object)?

Comment: I assume you mean a [JLS-15.9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5) Anonymous Class. The JLS says (in part) *an anonymous class is always an inner class (§8.1.3); it is never static (§8.1.1, §8.5.1).* Regardless, at the end of the method invocation it goes out of scope (unless it's assigned to a different, `static`, reference).

Comment: @AlexVPerl there is no enclosing object, and anonymous classes in static methods have no parent reference.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that it does not require an instance of that class, but it does require an instance of java.lang.Class that represents the class that contains the method. The Class instance instantiation and garbage collection is handled by the JVM via ClassLoaders.

Answer (score 7):

Say you have

```
static class Foo
{
    static Bar bar = new Bar();

    static int func(){ ... }
}
```

obviously, a `Foo` object will not be created for calling `func()`.

However, the class `Foo` needs to be loaded in memory; and to the application, there is an object corresponding to the class, which can be referred to as `Foo.class`, or `Class.forName("Foo")`.

A loaded class is not initialized yet. When you call a static method for the 1st time, the class is initialized; some "space" is allocated for static variables, and static initializer code (like `new Bar()`) is executed.

This "space" is not visible to application as an object; but it's an in memory data structure too that concerns garbage collections (and other objects it refers to, like `bar`)

The class, and the "space", are only eligible for GC when the classloader that loaded the class is eligible for GC. For usual command line applications, that never happens. But for a lot of other applications, class GC is important, and class loading needs to be carefully done.

Comment: Unless it's changed in Java 8, "static class" doesn't make sense in Java unless it's a nested class.

Answer (score 4):

`static` methods belong to the class, not to the object reference. You can call `static` method and forget about wasting memory on creating an object reference of the class being used, that doesn't happen. When you call an `static` method on an object reference, you get a compiler warning on the subject. You can even call `static` methods on a variable of the desired class and this variable can be `null`, the `static` method will be invoked with no problem.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }
}

//works, no instance of Foo was created
Foo.sayHello("AlexVPerl");
Foo foo = new Foo();
//works, compiler raises a warning here
foo.sayHello("AlexVPerl");
foo = null;
//works, compiler raises a warning here
//and as you can see, it doesn't matter if the instance is null
foo.sayHello("AlexVPerl");
```